# What evidence is there on the medical effects of circumcision?

Tags: medicine

If this is the wrong place to post this question, then I will delete it and post it were it belongs.

I have heard many conflicting things about circumcision.  I have heard that it reduces the rate of STDs, including AIDS, and cancer in the man and his wife.  On the other hand, I have also heard that circumcising babies can cause psychological harm and increases the rate of urinary tract infections.  Are there any reliable studies on this issue and what do the conclude?

Thank you for any and all answers.

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered over at the [Skeptics site](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) in great detail.

See [Does circumcision reduce HIV risk?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/does-circumcision-reduce-hiv-risk) and [Does circumcision lead to a net increase in quality of life?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/does-circumcision-lead-to-a-net-increase-in-quality-of-life). The answers are well-sourced and there are answers addressing both sides of the issue.

Comment: This is community wiki since it doesn't really add any new information outside of links to another stackexchange site. Feel free to add more links and resources if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I will go to the skeptics site and read those links.